# Muzzle flash on a gun

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

Is there a way to make muzzle flash come out of a gun using the smoke simulator with fire and smoke?  I've seen a lot of tutorials that use an object coming out of the gun that lights up, but it doesn't seem to look as realistic as real fire.

Thanks

Comment: This tut may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKc8WNNV4Bw

Comment: Yeah that's the one I was watching.  It looks great, but when I watch actual videos of muzzle flash, it looks more like a flash of fire but still evolving or growing like the way fire would from an emitter.  Not sure if that's being too picky :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you wouldn't want to create a muzzle flash using a smoke simualtion. The flash is only visible for one frame.

I'd recommend you to parent a plane to your gun and create a Material for the flash with animated transparency.
Plug an image texture of the flash into an emission shader, so the flash illuminates the scene accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Wow nice!  This is a very interesting method.  I wonder if a video texture would be overkill?

Comment: I used a video texture from the commercial action essentials collection. The big advantage would be, that the muzzleflashes are unique and don't look the same the whole time. Also you don't need to keyframe the transparency for each gunshot.

Comment: That's amazing!  Such a great solution.  I will check out that collection.  Thanks again